# Why is ArrayList printing only one object type

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Having trouble in Java with printing the ArrayList where I store the objects. When I store two different types of objects and I ask to display what is stored in the array, it spits out only one type but twice.

```
Transaction withdrawal = new Transaction("Withdraw", "12/23/2021", 50.0);
Transaction deposit = new Transaction("Deposit", "12/22/2021", 25.0);
Transaction inquiry = new Transaction("Inquiry", "12/25/2021", 0.0);
    
Transaction.transactionList.add(inquiry);
Transaction.transactionList.add(deposit);
Transaction.transactionList.add(withdrawal);

System.out.println(Transaction.transactionList);
```

Here's the class along with the constructor

```
public class Transaction {
//define variables
static double amount;
static String type;
static String date;
static String zeroTransaction;
static ArrayList transactionList = new ArrayList();


public Transaction(String type, String date, double amount) {
    //constructor
    Transaction.type = type;
    Transaction.date = date;
    Transaction.amount = amount;        
}
```

And here's the output:

```
[[Inquiry,12/25/2021,0.0], [Inquiry,12/25/2021,0.0], [Inquiry,12/25/2021,0.0]]
```

Comment: Hint: *all* your fields are static. I suggest you research what the `static` modifier does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your attributes are static and when you create the last object `Transaction inquiry = new Transaction("Inquiry", "12/25/2021", 0.0);` it replaces all previous values of `withdrawal` and `deposit`.

A static variable is common to all the instances (or objects) of the class because it is a class level variable. In other words you can say that only a single copy of static variable is created and shared among all the instances of the class. Memory allocation for such variables only happens once when the class is loaded in the memory.

You have to remove the static keyword and the type of attributes inside the constructor.

```
public class Transaction {
double amount;
 String type;
 String date;
 String zeroTransaction;
 ArrayList transactionList = new ArrayList();


public Transaction(String type, String date, double amount) {
    this.type = type;
    this.date = date;
    this.amount = amount;        
}
```

Comment: Man, thank you so much. I've always used static because it just worked.